# How to set X-Content-Type-Options on Azure App Service Linux?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, zap

I have an Angular2 web app deployed on Azure App Service Linux. I ran OWASP ZAP to attack my website and it alerted about X-Content-Type-Options Header missing. I was looking for the httpd file in etc/ to set X-Content-Type-Options = 'nosniff' but I couldn't find it. I assumed that the web app is running on Apache.

Reference:

`The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'. This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type. Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the issue by having the two files `ecosystem.config.js` and `serve.json` be part of our deployed artifact.

`ecosystem.config.js`

```
// https://burkeknowswords.com/this-is-how-to-easily-deploy-a-static-site-to-azure-96c77f0301ff
// Use PM2 to serve files on Linux App Service
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            script: "npx serve -s"
        }
    ]
};
```

`serve.json`

```
{
    "headers": [
        {
            "source" : "**",
            "headers" : [
                {
                    "key" : "X-Content-Type-Options",
                    "value" : "nosniff"
                },
                // more headers
```